# How to Invoke PubNub Chat multiple times on same page?

Tags: javascript, pubnub

So I'm trying to fit PubNub's really simple chat code to my needs in having multiple chats on one page. Here's the faulty **[demo](http://codepen.io/Kragalon/pen/incLB)** and original code:

```
  Enter Chat and press enter
<div><input id="input" placeholder="Say something!" /></div> 
Chat Output
<div id="box"></div>


<script src=http://cdn.pubnub.com/pubnub.min.js></script>
<script>
  (function(){
var box = PUBNUB.$('box'), input = PUBNUB.$('input'), channel = 'chat';
PUBNUB.subscribe({
channel : channel,
callback : function(text) { box.innerHTML = (''+text).replace( /[<>]/g, '' ) + '<br>' + box.innerHTML }
});
PUBNUB.bind( 'keyup', input, function(e) {
(e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && PUBNUB.publish({
channel : channel, message : input.value, x : (input.value='')
})
} )
})()

</script>
```

I'm not very good at JS, but I assumed the code in the demo would work, as I just changed the id and variable names. Thanks for the help, if this could work I'd be golden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing `;` between your two block codes after `()`

```
// ...
})
} )
})();
```

^^ This one ^^

```
  (function(){
var box1 = PUBNUB.$('box1'), input1 = PUBNUB.$('input1'), channel = 'chat';
// ...
```

Fixed code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/odhle

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was just a dumb mistake. Hey, do you happen to have experience with PubNub?